# Why is `math.asin` giving the wrong result?

Tags: python, math

I am working on this code and I have an issue with finding the inverse of sin.
I am not sure why it gives me the wrong numbers.

```
import math  
x=int(input("first side:"))  
y=int(input("second side:"))  
C=y**2+x**2  
c=math.sqrt(C)  
d=(x/c)  
f=math.asin(d)  
q=180-f  
print(d)  
print(f)  
print(q)
```

Comment: `math.asin` returns the value in radians. You are assuming that you get back the answer in degrees.

Comment: One look at the documentation, which says, "Return the arc sine of x, **in radians.**", would have resolved this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944164/math-asin-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not understanding the output. It's measured in Radians. Try:

```
print(180 * d / pi) # or degrees(d)
```